# visual web developer resize "all images" together?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, controls, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I have a weird problem with images in visual web developer,

I cant change my images properties from properties panel (my changes don't take effect) and all images in my website have gotten the same size

when I resize one image (by dragging the border), all images get that new size?

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow visual web developer read the image class in the CSS file instead of the properties of the control because there is something like this in my CSS file:

```
img {
width:260px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically the width and height properties of the HTML `<img />` have been deprecated for some time, you are recommended to use styles instead.

VS then takes this to the extreme, and instead of using inline styles, will create a new style in the default style sheet location for `img`, as you've discovered.

However, unless you are using the image full size somewhere you are better off resizing the image before you upload it to the server, saving on everyones bandwidth.

Also, IE does pretty poor things with it's default scaling routine, but you can turn on cubic sampling through css.

Comment: I was just caught out by the same thing - this is utterly stupid and indefensible behaviour by visual studio.